# html to PDF with new page detection

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, dynamic

I'm writing a PDF document using html. The PDF have multiple pages and the length of each page can vary. I would like to show an image at the start of each page. For this, I need to detect when there is a new page of the PDF document in the html code. I don't know if this is possible.

I don't know what code I can write to solve this issue

Comment: Simply use header : set a header which contains the image